# PHP How to implement flash messages

Tags: php

I'm working on a small custom CMS and would like to implement flash messages. I have searched for hours, but I can't find anything that behaves the way I want. And I can't seem to make anything work.

I want to be able to pass a variable (via $_SESSION) to another page and, on that next request, it will be removed. I want to be able to use a keep_flash function, in case I don't want the message to be removed with the next server request.

Can anyone send me in the right direction? I can't really make anything work.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is some code I am playing with. It sort-of works. When you first visit the page, it sets the $_SESSION and everything is fine. But if you refresh, now it deletes the $_SESSION. If you refresh again, it adds it back...etc. So, if you were to visit the page, refresh, then go to another page the flash message wouldn't be in the $_SESSION. So how can I fix this?

```
class flash
{
private $current = array();
private $keep    = array();

public function __construct()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash'])) {
        foreach($_SESSION['flash'] as $k=>$v)
        {
            $this->current[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}

public function __destruct()
{   
    foreach ($this->current as $k=>$v)
    {           
        if (array_key_exists($k,$this->keep) && $this->keep[$k] == $v) {
            // keep flash
            $_SESSION['flash'][$k] = $v;

        } else {
            // delete flash
            unset($_SESSION['flash'][$k]);
            unset($this->current[$k]);
            unset($this->keep[$k]);
        }           
    }
}

public function setFlash($key,$value)
{
    $_SESSION['flash'][$key] = $value;
}

public function keepFlash($key)
{
    $this->keep[$key] = $this->getFlash($key);
}

public function getFlash($key)  
{       
    if (array_key_exists($key,$this->current)) return $this->current[$key];

    return null;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

basic idea is to have script always check specific variable in session (usually called 'flash') for content - if not empty display and delete it from session. When message is needed just place is same variable in session and next check would pick it up....

keep_flash in your case would not proceed with delete, or move to other place based on your needs.

for implementation just google it - usually it wrapped in some kind of class - I personally like phpclasses.org or part of framework

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post, I added a chunk of code. Your solution would work except that it is basically like using the $_SESSION by itself. I want my class to delete all flash messages that are not explicitly kept. So, if you set four flash messages on page1.php, on page2.php even if you only call one of them, they should all be deleted if none were kept with a keep method.

Comment: I know you had ask this question long time ago. But this can be helpful for you http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/